# Add git information to create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, create-react-app

In development, I want to be able to see the build information (git commit hash, author, last commit message, etc) from the web. I have tried:

- use child_process to execute a git command line, and read the result (Does not work because browser environment)
- generate a buildInfo.txt file during `npm build` and read from the file (Does not work because fs is also unavailable in browser environment)
- use external libraries such as "git-rev"

The only thing left to do seems to be doing `npm run eject` and applying https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-revision-webpack-plugin , but I really don't want to eject out of create-react-app. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, turns out there is no way to achieve this without ejecting, so the workaround I used is:

1) in package.json, define a script `"git-info": "git log -1 --oneline > src/static/gitInfo.txt"`

2) add `npm run git-info` for both start and build

3) In the config js file (or whenever you need the git info), i have

```
const data = require('static/gitInfo.txt')
fetch(data).then(result => {
    return result.text()
})
```

Answer (score 99):

On a slight tangent (no need to eject and works in develop),
this may be of help to other folk looking to add their current git commit SHA into their index.html as a meta-tag by adding:

```
REACT_APP_GIT_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
```

to the build script in the package.json and then adding (note it MUST start with REACT_APP... or it will be ignored):

```
<meta name="ui-version" content="%REACT_APP_GIT_SHA%">
```

into the index.html in the public folder.

Within react components, do it like this:

```html
<Component>{process.env.REACT_APP_GIT_SHA}</Component>
```

Comment: I like it, even though it does not work on localhost when developing, only after building a production version.

Comment: @BugsBunny Should work the same way. Just add the assignment to `start` script as well. `"start": "REACT_APP_GIT_SHA=\`git rev-parse --short HEAD\` react-scripts start"`

Comment: @uidevthing how did you know to use backticks to get substitution working in a package.json script?? I just blew a couple of hours pulling my hair out trying to get this to work before stumbling on your solution. It worked perfectly, btw!

Comment: This is not a cross-platform solution. Will not work on Windows with either Powershell or cmd.

Comment: @AbhyudayaSharma [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) could very easily replace the mentioned script

Comment: `cross-env` will not work for this without having to change your `npm` config; see here: https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/192#issuecomment-513341729

Comment: This syntax does not work with yarn 2, however the $() syntax does - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48392/understanding-backtick

Comment: "REACT_APP_GIT_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD` react-scripts start". How can I run this command in windows cmd?

Comment: @RohitVyas not really sure what you mean exactly but if you type:
git rev-parse --short HEAD into the CLI you will get that git commit SHA like "17c0b12".
for "REACT_APP_GIT_SHA=git rev-parse --short HEAD I run it by assigning it to a npm script in the package.json file and for example I call it build
So then in the CLI if I run npm build it will execute this script.
Hope this is of some help, thanks.

Comment: I asked because this command is working in mac system but not working in windows cmd.

Answer (score 15):

I created another option inspired by Yifei Xu's response that utilizes es6 modules with create-react-app.  This option creates a javascript file and imports it as a constant inside of the build files. While having it as a text file makes it easy to update, this option ensures it is a js file packaged into the javascript bundle. The name of this file is _git_commit.js

package.json scripts:

```
"git-info": "echo export default \"{\\\"logMessage\\\": \\\"$(git log -1 --oneline)\\\"}\"  > src/_git_commit.js",
"precommit": "lint-staged",
"start": "yarn git-info; react-scripts start",
"build": "yarn git-info; react-scripts build",
```

A sample component that consumes this commit message:

```
import React from 'react';

/**
 * This is the commit message of the last commit before building or running this project
 * @see ./package.json git-info for how to generate this commit
 */
import GitCommit from './_git_commit';

const VersionComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Git Log: {GitCommit.logMessage}</h1>
  </div>
);

export default VersionComponent;
```

Note that this will automatically put your commit message in the javascript bundle, so do ensure no secure information is ever entered into the commit message. I also add the created _git_commit.js to .gitignore so it's not checked in (and creates a crazy git commit loop).

Answer (score 11):

It was impossible to be able to do this without `eject`ing until Create React App 2.0 ([Release Notes](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html)) which brought with it automatic configuration of Babel Plugin Macros which run at compile time. To make the job simpler for everyone, I wrote one of those macros and published an NPM package that you can import to get git information into your React pages: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-git-info

With it, you can do it like this:

```
import GitInfo from 'react-git-info/macro';

const gitInfo = GitInfo();

...

render() {
  return (
    <p>{gitInfo.commit.hash}</p>
  );
}
```

The project [README](https://github.com/AbhyudayaSharma/react-git-info#readme) has some more information. You can also see a live demo of the package working [here](https://abhyudaya.dev/).

Comment: While this does add another package it is a super-clean & useful way to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 9):

My approach is slightly different from @uidevthing's answer. I don't want to pollute package.json file with environment variable settings.

You simply have to run another script that save those environment variables into `.env` file at the project root. That's it.

In the example below, I'll use typescript but it should be trivial to convert to javascript anyway.

#### package.json

If you use javascript it's `node scripts/start.js`

```
  ...
  "start": "ts-node scripts/start.ts && react-scripts start",
```

#### scripts/start.ts

Create a new script file `scripts/start.ts`

```
const childProcess = require("child_process");
const fs = require("fs");

function writeToEnv(key: string = "", value: string = "") {
  const empty = key === "" && value === "";

  if (empty) {
    fs.writeFile(".env", "", () => {});
  } else {
    fs.appendFile(".env", `${key}='${value.trim()}'\n`, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  }
}

// reset .env file
writeToEnv();

childProcess.exec("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD", (err, stdout) => {
  writeToEnv("REACT_APP_GIT_BRANCH", stdout);
});
childProcess.exec("git rev-parse --short HEAD", (err, stdout) => {
  writeToEnv("REACT_APP_GIT_SHA", stdout);
});

// trick typescript to think it's a module
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/56577324/9449426
export {};
```

The code above will setup environment variables and save them to `.env` file at the root folder. They must start with `REACT_APP_`. React script then automatically reads `.env` at build time and then defines them in `process.env`.

#### App.tsx

```
...
console.log('REACT_APP_GIT_BRANCH', process.env.REACT_APP_GIT_BRANCH)
console.log('REACT_APP_GIT_SHA', process.env.REACT_APP_GIT_SHA)
```

#### Result

```
REACT_APP_GIT_BRANCH master
REACT_APP_GIT_SHA 042bbc6
```

More references:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Comment: Worked like a charm 

Comment: works well for react native

Answer (score 2):

If your `package.json` scripts are always executed in a unix environment you can achieve the same as in @NearHuscarl answer, but with fewer lines of code by initializing your `.env` dotenv file from a shell script. The generated `.env` is then [picked up by the react-scripts](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) in the subsequent step.

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "sh ./env.sh && react-scripts start"
  "build": "sh ./env.sh && react-scripts build",
}
```

where `.env.sh` is placed in your project root and contains code similar to the one below to override you `.env` file content on each build or start.

```sh
{
  echo BROWSER=none
  echo REACT_APP_FOO=bar
  echo REACT_APP_VERSION=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
  echo REACT_APP_APP_BUILD_DATE=$(date)
  # ...
} > .env
```

Since the `.env` is overridden on each build, you may consider putting it on the `.gitignore` list to avoid too much noise in your commit diffs.

**Again the disclaimer:** This solution only works for environments where a bourne shell interpreter or similar exists, i.e. unix.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily inject your git information like commit hash into your index.html using [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) and [craco-interpolate-html-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-interpolate-html-plugin). Such way you won't have to use `yarn eject` and it also works for development server environment along with production builds.

After installing CRACO the following config in `craco.config.js` worked for me:

```
const interpolateHtml = require('craco-interpolate-html-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: interpolateHtml,
      // Enter the variable to be interpolated in the html file
      options: {
        BUILD_VERSION: require('child_process')
          .execSync('git rev-parse HEAD', { cwd: __dirname })
          .toString().trim(),
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

and in your `index.html`:
`<meta name="build-version" content="%BUILD_VERSION%" />`

Here are the lines of code to add in `package.json` to make it all work:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided above are covering a wide range of scenarios, but I couldn't find any that offers a vanilla JS and cross-platform solution. @NearHuscarl's solution overwrites entirely the content of `.env`, which is not convinient when it contains other values. Here's a solution that only updates the file.
I define a new script which calls my JS snippet before my usual react-scripts commands :

### package.json

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "git-version": "node scripts/set_env.js",
        "start": "yarn run git-version && react-scripts start",
        "build": "yarn run git-version && react-scripts build",
        
    },
}
```

The script itself is run with Node and requires no external dependencies (apart from having a Node environment). It will update the `.env` file with the `REACT_APP_VERSION=XX` property added or updated. The original content is kept as is. If the file does not exist it will be created.

### scripts/set_env.js

```js
const childProcess = require("child_process");
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");
const readline = require("readline");

const PREFIX = "REACT_APP_VERSION=";

// Append current git version on .env file https://stackoverflow.com/a/77133455/7961775
function writeToEnv(content) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(".env");
        let output = "";
        let hasVersion = false;

        const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
            input: fileStream,
            crlfDelay: Infinity,
        });

        fileStream.on("error", (err) => {
            readInterface.close();
            fileStream.close();
            reject(err);
        });

        readInterface.once("error", (err) => {
            readInterface.close();
            fileStream.close();
            if (err.includes("Error: ENOENT:")) {
                console.info(".env file not found, will create it", err);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });

        readInterface.on("line", (line) => {
            let lineToAppend = "";

            if (!hasVersion && line.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
                lineToAppend = content;
                hasVersion = true;
            } else {
                lineToAppend = line;
            }

            output += lineToAppend + (lineToAppend.endsWith(os.EOL) ? undefined : os.EOL);
        });

        readInterface.on("close", () => {
            if (!hasVersion) {
                // File was not found
                output += content + os.EOL;
            }
            fs.writeFile(".env", output, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const tags = childProcess.execSync("git describe --tags").toString().trim();
        const reactVersion = `${PREFIX}${tags}`;
        console.info(`Setting ${reactVersion}`);
        await writeToEnv(reactVersion);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Could not set ${PREFIX}`, err);
    }
})();
```