# React (CRA) Service Worker Cache "public" folder

Tags: android, service-worker, create-react-app, static-files

After executing the create-react-app and enabling the service workers in the `index.js`, all relevant files from the `src` folder are cached. However some of my resources reside in the `public` directory. When I run `npm run build`, the `asset-manifest.json` and `precache-manifest.HASH.js` only contain the HTML, mangled JS and CSS (all stuff from the `src` folder).

**How can I tell the service worker to additionally cache specific files from the `public` folder?**

Here is the actually generated `precache-manifest.e431838417905ad548a58141f8dc754b.js`

```
self.__precacheManifest = [
  {
    "revision": "cb0ea38f65ed9eddcc91",
    "url": "/grafiti/static/js/runtime~main.cb0ea38f.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "2c226d1577937984bf58",
    "url": "/grafiti/static/js/main.2c226d15.chunk.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "c88c70e5f4ff8bea6fac",
    "url": "/grafiti/static/js/2.c88c70e5.chunk.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "2c226d1577937984bf58",
    "url": "/grafiti/static/css/main.7a6fc926.chunk.css"
  },
  {
    "revision": "980026e33c706b23b041891757cd51be",
    "url": "/grafiti/index.html"
  }
];
```

But I want it to also contain entries for these urls:

- `/grafiti/icon-192.png`
- `/grafiti/icon-512.png`

They come from the `public` folder.

Alternatively: How can I add my icons for the `manifest.webmanifest` file in the `src` folder in a way such that I can reference them from the web manifest?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you search for a solution (like me) which works without ejecting. This approach worked for me:

1. Install the module [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) via `yarn add -D react-app-rewired`
2. Replace `react-scripts` in your npm scripts (not needed for eject) inside your package.json

   ```
   /* package.json */

   "scripts": {
   -   "start": "react-scripts start",
   +   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   -   "build": "react-scripts build",
   +   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
   -   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
   +   "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   ```
3. Create a config-overrides.js file in the same level as your package.json

My file looks like this (because I also want to add an own service worker with more sophisticated caching options for my apis) but **globPatterns** and the **globDirectory** is what your looking for. After adding this patterns, the matching files (in my case images, music and sounds) were added to the generated precache-manifest-{hash}.

```
const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpack: function(config, env) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new InjectManifest({
        globPatterns: [
          'images/*.png',
          'models/*.glb',
          'music/*.mp3',
          'sound/*.mp3'
        ],
        globDirectory: 'build',
        swSrc: path.join('src', 'custom-service-worker.js'),
        swDest: 'service-worker.js'
      })
    );

    return config;
  }
}
```

P.S.: if you need a custom-service.worker.js file to get it work, `workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([])`should be sufficient as content for this file, but [the workbox docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) are also very interesting for those caching stuff

Comment: Hi @Fabian, what if I don't have a custom worker file? how to use the default one by create-react-app? thanks.

Comment: Hi @dli, exactly for this cache and precache stuff I added my custom service worker. :) As far as I know it is not possible to modify the generated service worker of cra (without eject). This is why I suggested react-app-rewired + InjectManifest so you do not need to run eject.

Comment: Thank you @Fabian, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to go for a very basic solution without ejecting or rewiring, you could also do the following**:

Assuming you bootstrapped your project using something like `npx create-react-app app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript`, then in your `service-worker.ts` file replace [this line](https://github.com/cra-template/pwa/blob/25cb9f06938c671507684a8438c347d3c8bc8b24/packages/cra-template-pwa-typescript/template/src/service-worker.ts#L25)...

```
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

...with the following:

```
// default static file URLs generated during the build process
const staticBuildFiles = self.__WB_MANIFEST as PrecacheEntry[];

// extra file URLs you want to be precached
const extraPrecachedFiles: PrecacheEntry[] = [
  "/cats.f137634a.png",
  "/dogs.1d77f71c.jpg",
];

// register all assets to be precached by the service worker
precacheAndRoute([
  ...staticBuildFiles,
  ...essentialMediaFiles.map((url) => ({ url, revision: null }))
]);
```

For the sake of "cache-busting", the images in the solution above already include the revision information in form of hash numbers that were previously (manually) added to their filenames. As mentioned in the [workbox docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching):

> To have the revisioning information in the URL itself, is generally a best practice for static assets.

However, if for various reasons you do not want to include the revision hashes in the filenames in your source code, you could also pass a unique string as environment variable to your build command that you can pick up later to let workbox use it as a revision string to bust your cache. E.g. you could use the unix timestamp of the build process (or go for something fancier like [passing the current git commit hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68907358/2477619) information)...

```
REACT_APP_BUILD_VERSION=$(date +'%s') npm run build
```

... which you can then pick up in your `service-worker.ts`:

```
precacheAndRoute([
  ...staticBuildFiles,
  ...essentialMediaFiles.map((url) => ({ url, revision: process.env.REACT_APP_BUILD_VERSION }))
]);
```

The above code would result in all files using the `REACT_APP_BUILD_VERSION` as revision being invalidated on each build.