# React JS not precaching all files from public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently learning PWA with React JS (create-react-app). I need to precache the files so it can be loaded when it's offline. But somehow all the files from `public` folder won't precaching so it's failed whenever I accessing my website offline.

[image: failed]

[image: failed2]

all that status `failed` files was from public folder, while others like `background3.jpg` was imported from React `src`. I was told by my friend that it should be cached, but actually it didn't

Comment: Did you create a service worker and add code to precache site assets in the install event handler?
If so, share the code so we can help.

Comment: I just changed the `serviceWorker.unregister()` to `serviceWorker.register()` just like the React documentation.

Comment: I'm using `create-react-app`

Comment: The default scaffolding does not really create a service worker that does anything. You still have to program your service worker to run logic you need to manage everything.
No site has the same caching rules as the next, so the react CLI cannot just create a magic service worker for everyone. You still need to write the code :)

Comment: as the documentation said, I don't need to edit the serviceWorker.js. I just need to `register` it or else I need to eject the `create-react-app` and create my own serviceWorker.js

Comment: that sounds great....but trust me you need to actually develop your service worker. I have built about 100 PWAs so far and a few were even React apps. I had to create custom service workers for each application.
There is not a good way to just magically manage how your specific application assets are cached, invalidated, etc. No one size fits all.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve your issue? I am starting with react.js PWA and I'm stuck at the exact same problem, I did try to develop my own service-worker but i am getting even more errors...

Comment: you need to build your custom service worker like @ChrisLove mentioned

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you can't modify service workers entirely freely in create-react-app without ejecting your app. Having said that there are dev libraries out there like react-app-rewired that allow to modify parts of the build process without ejecting. Currently facing a similar issue, this might help --

[React (CRA) SW Cache "public" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840929/react-cra-sw-cache-public-folder)