# Why is --isolatedModules error fixed by any import?

Tags: typescript

In a create-react-app typescript project, I tried to write this just to test some stuff quickly:

```js
// experiment.test.ts
it('experiment', () => {
  console.log('test');
});
```

But it gives me the following error, with a red squiggly beneath `it`:

> All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.

However, if I change the file to the following, then everything apparently is fine (except for the unused import of course):

```js
// experiment.test.ts
import { Component} from 'react'; // literally anything, don't even have to use it

it('test', () => {
  console.log('test');
});
```

Why? What is happening here? What does `--isolatedModules` actually mean/do?

Comment: If you're using `import` or `export` then that file is an ES6 module. Your top example is problematic because `it` is not defined anywhere, in a modular architecture you'd need to import `it` from somewhere

Comment: @apokryfos This link should help

https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/next-js-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-987174737331

Comment: This also seems like a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925133/proxy-to-backend-with-default-next-js-dev-server

Answer (score 460, accepted):

Typescript treats files without import/exports as legacy script files. As such files are not modules and any definitions they have get merged in the global namespace. `isolatedModules` forbids such files.

Adding any import or export to a file makes it a module and the error disappears.

**Also `export {}` is a handy way** to make a file a module without importing anything.

Comment: If you don't want `isolatedModules` just set them to `false`.

Comment: It is like adding some rule and then ignoring it by adding `@ts-ignore`. The `export {}` is just a different syntax, way of bypassing the rule, but in principle is exactly that.

Comment: I don't see an issue with having general rules that are followed 99% of the time, but that sometimes needs to be broken. Having to "break a rule", as long as the rule generally is a good one, it forces me to think about what I'm doing and consider if there are better ways to solve something. And sometimes there isn't. Like in this case, where I was just making a test-file to try something out.

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, can whate are legacy script files? can you give any examples?

Comment: In my case I just had to give the exported variable the same name as the filename - and it was fixed! You may need to restart the dev server.

Answer (score 108):

The correct way is to tell TypeScript what you want. If you don't want `isolatedModules` create `tsconfig.json` inside your `test` directory and add:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": false
  },
}
```

Adding `"isolatedModules": true` to the config and then cheating TypeScript checker by adding empty `export {}` smells bad code to me.

Comment: as explained in other comments, in this particular case, it won't be counted as code smell, it's a necessity over here, since there is no other way to partially exclude some file from the isolutedModules rule

Comment: Hmm, when I frob true to false, I am told in reply:


    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'isolatedModules' of object '# 
   <Object>'
        at verifyTypeScriptSetup

Comment: @JerryAsher same here man, but it worked earlier and then I reverted some code and tried to run it, which is when I got the exact same error.

Comment: This didn't work for me because I got this message: `The following mandatory changes were made to your tsconfig.json:
- isolatedModules was set to true (requirement for SWC / Babel)`

Comment: Personally, I prefer the `export {}` because you can generally enforce `isolatedModules`, but explicitly show files that are the exception.

Answer (score 19):

Still having error despite you exporting things from that "error file"?

1. `Check if you don't export same name that you already export in another file` (conflict)
2. `After your fix try to stop and start your npm/yarn runner` (I experienced it cannot recover itself even after hard reload of the page especially when you have another error somewhere else)

Comment: or in my case:

3. Make sure there's not an empty file with the same name which you were mistakenly checking

Answer (score 10):

In case you don't want to add the unnecessary

```
export {}
```

everywhere and don't want to ruin the compiler option for other files.

If you have a separate `tests/` directory, you can extend the root directory `tsconfig` file and create a new one in the `tests/` directory.

Then add this to it:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "isolatedModules": false
    },
}
```

This turns off the `isolatedModules` flag only for test files. Restart your code-editor to sync the changes.

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately I don't have a separate `tests` directory though, as it's much easier to stay organized when tests are co-located with the file they're testing.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to check isolated modules. When I checked Google, there is no direct context of it.

It basically means that you allow Typescript to compile modules in isolation.

But it comes from Typescript and has something to do with Typescript preferring modules over namespaces.

> Modules also have a dependency on a module loader (such as
> CommonJs/Require.js) or a runtime which supports ES Modules. Modules
> provide for better code reuse, stronger **isolation** and better tooling
> support for bundling.

[Source 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html)

Using a create-react-app typescript project,
you should have installed typescript and ts-jest (or the create-react-app should handle the dependencies based on wether you ejected the app or not).

Also `ts-jest` has some information about it:

> By default ts-jest uses TypeScript compiler in the context of a
> project (yours), with full type-checking and features. But it can also
> be used **to compile each file separately**, what TypeScript calls an
> ‘isolated module’. That’s what the isolatedModules option (which
> defaults to false) does.

[Source 2](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/isolatedModules)

As soon as you use the `export` command you are creating a module out of what is being exported.

If you are using ts-jest, you can add these settings without affecting your other modules, which the create-react-app will consist off.

```json
"ts-jest": {
  "isolatedModules": false
}
```

And checkout the ts-jest page (second source) for the pro's and con's.

Comment: Doing this in my jest.config.js resolved it --  `    'ts-jest': { tsconfig: { isolatedModules: false }` however, if I just do an import from another file it also converts it to a module and then this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding `export {};` was not enough.

I met this error in the `webpack.config.ts` file. The error message looked like this:

> 'webpack.config.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.ts(1208)

When I added `export {};` I got another error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ‘export'
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)…

I tried to change `tsconfig.json` module option from:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "EsNext",
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
```

to:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
```

,because *webpack.config.ts* had commonjs syntax like `module.export ={}`. Unfortunately, it didn't work too. I discovered that there were no type definitions added to the project, so I run:

```
npm install --save-dev ts-node @types/node @types/webpack
```

and everything was fine. The file was recognized as a module thanks to `export {};`.

Of course, using `export {};` to make the file a module is just a workaround, not a solution. I could

- change webpack.config file extension to .js instead of .ts and stay with the commonJS module format
- change to import/export statements in ES modules format and use the .mjs file extension, because Node.js has stable support for ES modules since version 13.2.0 was introduced. Nevertheless, that would trigger other problems with changing commonJS syntax
  [Can I use as es-modules for webpack config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59407534/can-i-use-as-es-modules-for-webpack-config)
- leave .ts file extension, follow the webpack configuration guide for typescript and use ES modules
  [link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/)

I chose the third option and had to add `import 'webpack-dev-server';` to avoid type errors. My configuration changed from this:

```js
export {};

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env) => {...}
```

to this:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import 'webpack-dev-server';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

const config = (env: { [x: string]: any; }): webpack.Configuration => {...}
export default config;
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because you haven't imported the function to be tested yet. Once you do that, the error will disappear. The accepted answer explains why.

Answer (score -4):

how about just do
`.eslintignore`
add the file folder where u need to ignore from eslint so no errors on that --isolatedModules error fixed by any imports
and u can test your logics their

Answer (score -4):

**Problem solving, see article** https://blog.csdn.net/qingfeng812/article/details/120510673

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).