# Can I use as es-modules for webpack config?

Tags: node.js, webpack, es6-modules

I am using node 13.4.0. with es modules (via .mjs extensions).

Using webpack config files as es modules crashes:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /path-to-config-dir/webpack.config.mjs
```

Simplest es module **webpack.config.mjs**:

```
export default {};
```

Does webpack support es-modules for config files? I couldn't find a lot of information on that topic. I've found this (an issue closed in June 2019):

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/9226

So I am wondering about the state of webpack config files regarding mjs. Can anybody point me to some documentation on this?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this ?

Comment: nope, still using cjs modules

Comment: Thank your for the question. Sometimes in official webpack documentation, you may find some snippets written in es6, what apparently makes no sense, due the lack of support (rather node or webpack)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using Node v14.16.0 and Webpack 5.37.0. Although it's not documented, a configuration file named `webpack.config.mjs` seems to be picked up automatically, and is interpreted as a module.

Some caveats though:

- `import { Something } from 'webpack'` does not work. Use this instead:

  ```
    import webpack from 'webpack'
    const { Something } = webpack
  ```
- `__dirname` is frequently used in Webpack configs, but isn't available in a module. To bring it back:

  ```
    import path from 'path'
    const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname)
  ```

Comment: Though it's a while ago, I've asked this question, this makes for a good answer. I like the __dirname solution in particular. Quite nice!

Comment: Note: This is not entirely correct. To replace `__dirname` use
`import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';const __dirname = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);`
and replace `module.exports` with `export`.
See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28114

Comment: Make that `const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(new URL(import.meta.url)))`