# Proxy to backend with default Next.js dev server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Before, when I made apps with create-react-app, I would have a `setupProxy.js` file that would route API requests similar to this

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/api',
        proxy({
            target: 'http://localhost:8000',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

But that doesn't seem to work with next.js.  When I do the same thing, I get various errors.

Googling a solution, a lot say to use a custom server of some kind.  But how would I accomplish a proxy like above using the default nextjs dev server? (Equivalent of `npm run dev` when `dev` in my package.json is `next dev`.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

There is now an official feature for this in the config: **Rewrites**

Besides normal path rewrites, they can also proxy requests to another webserver

**`next.config.js`:**

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: 'http://localhost:8000/:path*' // Proxy to Backend
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See [Next.js Docs Rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

Comment: this one is not working when i want WebSocket proxy. it's handshake is failing.

Comment: @nemishzalavadiyaneel socket.io doesn't work for me either using rewrites... Were you able to find a solution that does not involve creating a custom server?

Comment: I still do not. I am creating `const` object and storing hardcoded URL there. share it if you find any solution.

Comment: I believe `Rewrites` just basic proxy setup. More proxy configuration need to setup custom server

Comment: Incase anyone is handling this in their nginx config in production here is how to make config options development only. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction

Comment: Though, there is issue with `https` -- `Error: self signed certificate` https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21537

Comment: Rewrites look fantastic, until you realise that environment variables are baked in at build-time which is a deal-breaker for multi-environment deployments 
 https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21888

Comment: Works. However, the example should probably have: `destination: "http://localhost:8000/api/:path*"`. Note the `/api/` part.

Comment: does it work when you trying to map external domain?

Comment: I run into the problem that getStaticProps can't fetch the data when I run `next build` and `next start` because the frontend (and therefore the proxy) is offline. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: this seems to do an 308 redirect, not really a proxy.

Answer (score 7):

My **`server.js`** set up, hope it helps:

```
import express from 'express';
import next from 'next';
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.use(
        '/api',
        proxy({
            target: process.env.API_HOST,
            changeOrigin: true,
        }),
    );
 
    server.all('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));

    server.listen(port, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```

**`package.json`**:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node -r esm server.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node -r esm server.js",
},
```

Comment: `NODE_ENV=development node -r esm server.js`

Comment: If using `require` then `const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');`

Comment: import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';

Comment: also, i did `node server.mjs` and dropped all of the ESM custom malarkey. node 15 plays nicely w/ esm in mjs files :)

Comment: hihi, did you do this? I did ti and the build/nodemon was too long

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with [catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) + `http-proxy-middleware`:

```
// pages/api/proxy/[...slug].js

import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware"; // @2.0.6

const proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
  target: process.env.BACKEND_URL,
  secure: false,
  pathRewrite: { "^/api/proxy": "" }, // remove `/api/proxy` prefix
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    externalResolver: true,
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}

export default function handler(req, res) {
  proxy(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    throw new Error(
      `Request '${req.url}' is not proxied! We should never reach here!`
    );
  });
}
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72310680

Comment: This works, but you'll also need to set the API Route config options to `{"externalResolver": true, "bodyParser": false}`. These respectively tell Next.js that the response is being handled by the proxy middleware, and to pass the raw request body to the proxy (otherwise non-GET requests will likely fail.)

Comment: Thx @soren121 just for confirmation, are these options of `createProxyMiddleware`?

Comment: No, these are options of Next.js API Routes, as documented here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config

Answer (score 2):

Rewrites didn't work for me, and neither did using axios `config.proxy`.

I've resorted to a good old constant:

```js
const SERVER_URL = 
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://produrl.com : 'http://localhost:8000';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/api/my-route`)
  // ...
}
```

I would much rather proxy requests and keep my requests cleaner, but I don't have a day to spend wrestling with this.

Maybe this very simple setup will help others.

Comment: this works on ssr only

Answer (score 0):

I have written a reverse-proxy `NPM package`, called [reverse_proxy_pathmapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reverse_proxy_pathmapper) that can be used to set up reverse proxy between frontend and backend.

Here is the Usage:

```js
import {ReverseProxyPathMapper} from "reverse_proxy_path_mapper";

const pathMapper = {
  "/api/?(.*)": "http://localhost:8000", // backend-api
  "/?(.*)": "http://localhost:3000" // frontend
                                    // ?(.*) -> Regex to match any
}

new ReverseProxyPathMapper({}, pathMapper).serve(9000);
```

Now access your frontend and backend on port `9000`. URL starting with `/api` will be sent to `backend` and others will be sent to `frontend`.

Comment: in which file this code will be written.

Comment: @Jocefyneroot This should be written in new file and use `node filename.js` (if you are using JS) or use `ts-node filename.js` (if you are using TS) to run this file.