# Can I use reverse proxy in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, reverse-proxy

I am facing a problem with revamping the project from **React + Nginx** to **Next.js**.

From my old project, the Nginx has a reverse proxy to redirect all API requests to another API server.

```
location /api/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;

    set $${fake}upstream_api ${NGINX_API_PROTO}://${NGINX_API_HOST};
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$${fake}1 break;
    proxy_pass $${fake}upstream_api$${fake}uri$${fake}is_args$${fake}args;

    include /etc/nginx/json/api_json_errors.conf;
}
```

Is it possible to using Next.js to do this job instead of Nginx?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxy to backend with default Next.js dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925133/proxy-to-backend-with-default-next-js-dev-server)