how to fix cors policy error in nextjs 14
why this error shows up?

I'm trying to reach my springboot server using axios. api work well in postman. but in nextjs its not work. how to fix this
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" }, // replace this your actual origin
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  experimental: {
    optimizePackageImports: ['@mantine/core', '@mantine/hooks'],

  },
};

export default nextConfig;

this is my next.config.mjs. i add this headers, but nothing change

I believe you need to proxy requests to backend like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65467719/14072498

Hi did you solve it ? if yes please share your solution

it fixed in backend and use axios
