# How to migrate service worker from JS to TS

Tags: typescript, eslint, service-worker

**Scenario**

I would like to change my service-worker file from javascript to typescript for better maintenance.
Here is my sw.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
  ...
});
...more handlers
```

**Problem**

I've changed a lot of lines to adapt my code to TS and ESlint requirements, but I have problem with `self` I recieve 2 errors from ESlint:

```
unexpected use of 'self' 
self is not defined
```

How to define self in Typescript file?

Comment: https://joshuatz.com/posts/2021/strongly-typed-service-workers/#solution-b-tsconfig-libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json` file it is needed to add `webworker` library

```
{
 ....
  "compilerOptions": {
  "lib": [
    ...
    "webworker"
  ],...
}
```

After adding webworker library it is possible to declare self with typescript `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`.

> [ServiceWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope) interface of the ServiceWorker API represents the global execution context of a service worker.

```
declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
```

If you have set `isolatedModules` flag to true in you tsconfig.json then you also need to add some import or export directive to your service worker file, because:

> Typescript treats files without import/exports as legacy script files. As such files are not modules and any definitions they have get merged in the global namespace. isolatedModules flag forbids such files.

If you do not need any import or export the handies way to make a file a module is add `export { };` [stack question describing this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577201/why-is-isolatedmodules-error-fixed-by-any-import/56577324)

At the end it is possible to use full typescript syntax in `sw.ts` file.

Comment: Unfortunately, "WebWorker" is incompatible with "DOM". Adding both to "lib" results in an error: "lib.dom.d.ts(25,1): error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file". More details: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14877

Answer (score 0):

you can import webworker lib in sw.ts

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
declare let self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

self.addEventListener('install', () => {
  // dosomething
});
```