# how to get serviceworker registration object which is typescript friendly?

Tags: typescript, service-worker

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event:any) {
  console.log('Push event!! ', event)
  
  if (event.data) {
    console.log('This push event has data: ', event.data.text());
  } else {
    console.log('This push event has no data.');
  }

  
  const promiseChain = showLocalNotification('Yolo', event.toString(), self.registration);

  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
  
})
```

Here the line  `const promiseChain = showLocalNotification('Yolo', event.toString(), self.registration);`
complains about `self.registration`:

```
Property 'registration' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)
```

How do I resolve this? Any pointer here would be greatly appreciated.

In my tsconfig i'm already using `dom` lib option.

`"lib": [ "es2015" , "dom"],`

Answer (score 15):

Add this to the top of your file:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
export default null
declare let self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope
```

Comment: What's `export default null`?

Comment: @azizj I don't understand it either, I just know it works. If someone else knows, enlighten us.

Comment: The reason for `export default null` is to prevent the error `TS1208: 'service-worker.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56577324/3927228).

Comment: worked even without `export default null`  for me.

Answer (score 11):

Please see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14877#issuecomment-493729050

The following two steps should help:

- Include a references to the `webworker` library in either your tsconfig's `compilerOptions` or via a [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) in your service worker TypeScript file.
- Inside your service worker TypeScript file, `declare var self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;` to tell TypeScript that `self` is an instance of the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped. Meanwhile i was using  `// @ts-ignore` comment to mask that error.
Your solution worked.

Comment: For some reason TS lets to re-declare `self` only with `export default null;`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also add `@types/global.d.ts` file and add:

```
export declare global {
  interface Window extends ServiceWorkerGlobalScope {}
  
  // need for addEventListener
  interface WindowEventMap extends ServiceWorkerGlobalScopeEventMap {}
}
```