# Following the official Cypress tutorial is causing "compiled under '--isolatedModules' " errors

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm a complete Cypress newbie working my way through the excellent [testing your first application](https://learn.cypress.io/testing-your-first-application) tutorial. However I've started to hit some compiler issues in the [third section](https://learn.cypress.io/testing-your-first-application/how-to-test-forms-and-custom-cypress-commands).

I've created a custom command as instructed, but am getting the following compiler error:

[image]

This [Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577201/why-is-isolatedmodules-error-fixed-by-any-import) seems to suggests adding `export {}` to my file.

If I do this the compiler error goes away in the `commands.ts` file but causes the introduction of the same error in another file. If I add the same `export {}` line this pushes the error to a new file. After repeating the cycle a few times eventually I end up with this error:

[image]

Can anybody provide me with any help that's aimed at a beginner? I'm struggling to know how to progress and was making good progress up to this point

Answer (score 5):

Adding `export {}` to the file is ok if you just want to get over the problem, but it's a bit of a hack - nobody designs a system to us a fake export to designate the file type.

The problem is likely in the `tsconfig` setup, check out [Typescript - What is a tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) (the Cypress docs are a bit light on the typescript side of things).

Also compare your setup to [cypress-realworld-app](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app) as it's a working implementation.

In the last file, I think your problem is the export is before the typings comment, try reversing them

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
export {}
```

---

Also see the 2nd answer on [Why is --isolatedModules error fixed by any import?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62694283/20706556), it seems it's good practice to have a `tsconfig` at the `/cypress` folder level just for tests. The realworld app also uses this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `cypress/index.ts` file to `cypress/cypress.d.ts`.
You don't need `reference` or `export` there.

Here's an example of my `cypress.d.ts` file:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      getByTestId(value: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
    }
  }
}
```

I highly recommend following the official tutorial in part of adding a separate `tsconfig` in cypress folder. IT's important to not have anything related to cypress in your main `tsconfig`.